# Presenting a ViewController From AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am writing a function that will be called when my application receives a remote notification locally. First, a banner is displayed using the library BRYXBanner, then if and when the user taps on the banner, it will call this function which should present a view controller called ChatLogViewController. This function may be called from any place within the app so one of the parameters for the function is fromViewController. I am trying to figure out two issues.

1. How to present ChatLogViewController from anywhere within the app using the function GoToChatLogVC()

Code:

```
func GoToClassVC(fromVC : UIViewController, toClassID: String) {
    let chatLog = ChatLogViewController()
    fromVC.present(chatLog, animated: true) {
        chatLog.classID = toClassID
    }
}
```

2. How to assign this function to a property of type (()->())?

[image: Screenshot of Function Code]

```
guard let currentVC = self.window?.currentViewController() else {
    print("ERROR")
    return
}

let banner = Banner(title: title, subtitle: body, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "MessageIcon"), backgroundColor: UIColor(red:40.00/255.0, green:170.0/255.0, blue:226/255.0, alpha:1.000))

banner.show(duration: 3.0)

banner.didTapBlock = GoToClassVC(fromVC: currentVC, toClassID: self.backgroundLaunchClassID)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use the notification and signal the concerned view controller with a notification object.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to present ViewController from anywhere then you can present it on `rootViewController` of `UIWindow` like below.

```
if let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    let chatLog = ChatLogViewController()
    rootVC.present(chatLog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> To solve this ERROR Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '(() -> ())?'

replace the code this

```
banner.didTapBlock = GoToClassVC(fromVC: currentVC, toClassID: self.backgroundLaunchClassID)
```

to this

```
banner.didTapBlock = {
             self.GoToClassVC(fromVC: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.visibleViewController()!, toClassID:"string")
        }
```

> For This: How to present `ChatLogViewController` from anywhere within the app using the function `GoToChatLogVC()`

Your `currentVC` replace to  `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.visibleViewController()!`

```
extension UIWindow {

    func visibleViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let rootViewController: UIViewController = self.rootViewController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: rootViewController)
        }
        return nil
    }

    class func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc:UIViewController) -> UIViewController {

        if vc.isKind(of:UINavigationController.self) {

            let navigationController = vc as! UINavigationController
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom( vc: navigationController.viewControllers.first!)

        } else if vc.isKind(of:UITabBarController.self) {

            let tabBarController = vc as! UITabBarController
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: tabBarController.selectedViewController!)

        }else if vc.isKind(of:UIAlertController.self) {

            let tabBarController = vc as! UIAlertController
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: tabBarController)

        } else {

            if let presentedViewController = vc.presentedViewController {
                if (presentedViewController.presentedViewController != nil){
                    return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: presentedViewController.presentedViewController!)
                }else{
                    return UIViewController()
                }

            } else {

                return vc;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works (almost), when the viewController loads, all of the IBOutlets are nil, is this due to the lack of a connection between the ViewController and the Storyboard Scene? If so, how would I go about linking the VC to the storyboard when I present it using this function?

Comment: @KylePapili can you please tell me how your are presenting your ViewController from storyboard? & what are the exact issue?

Comment: I've gotten this issue resolved but now another has arisen. I am instantiating a NavigationController, popping to the FirstViewController in that NavigationController, and then calling a segue from that FirstViewController which brings me to the desired ChatLogVC. HOWEVER, the NavigationController is embedded in a TabBarController which is NOT presented. How can I pop from the TabBarController to the NavigationController, then to the FirstVC so I am able to perform the desired segue? I have attached a link to a screenshot of my code. [link](https://imgur.com/a/FMuRc)

Answer (score 0):

To present a view controller from app delegate you can use the following:

```
let chatLog = ChatLogViewController()
window().rootViewController?.present(chatLog, animated: true) { _ in }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best approach is this:

1- add this extension at top of your AppDelegate class :

```
extension UIApplication{
    var topViewController: UIViewController?{
        if keyWindow?.rootViewController == nil{
            return keyWindow?.rootViewController
        }

        var pointedViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController

        while  pointedViewController?.presentedViewController != nil {
            switch pointedViewController?.presentedViewController {
            case let navagationController as UINavigationController:
                pointedViewController = navagationController.viewControllers.last
            case let tabBarController as UITabBarController:
                pointedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
            default:
                pointedViewController = pointedViewController?.presentedViewController
            }
        }
        return pointedViewController

    }
}
```

2- Now you can present your view controller easily:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "net")
application.topViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```